# Flutter: How to know item position inside a listview?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I have a list view of items but I would love to know how I can find its current position inside a listview, does anyone know?

Comment: What do you mean by position? Index is already there by which you can figure out the position.

Comment: I think he needs to know the last element visible on the screen.
so he can view count like 5/10

Answer (score 2):

Use a `ListView.builder` like this:

```
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: items.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
     return new Text('The Position is: $index');
    }
)
```

The index represents the position of the item.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question does not fall into this situation:

```
ListView.builder
  (
    itemCount: litems.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {      
     return new Text('my Index is: $index');
    }
  )
```

But rather on how to **know where** are you **currently scrolled**:

I would suggest to follow this [article](https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-lets-know-the-scrollcontroller-and-scrollnotification-652b2685a4ac)

```
Expanded(
            child: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
              onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
                // Basically you need something like:
                // final _index = scrollOffset (or position) / item height; 

              },
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 30,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(title: Text("Index : $index"));
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: What if you don't know the height of each item?

Comment: any solution so far ?